How to deploy the latest version of RStudio on a NAS?
I am using Synology NAS, and I'm deploying RStudio with Docker. Here is my YAML configuration:
version: '3'

services:
  8015-rstudio:
    image: rocker/rstudio:latest
    container_name: 8015-rstudio
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8015:8787
    volumes:
      - /volume2/docker/8015-rstudio/config:/home/rstudio/.config/rstudio
      - /volume2/docker/8015-rstudio/workspace:/home/rstudio/workspace
      - /volume2/docker/8015-rstudio/Renviron:/home/rstudio/.Renviron
    environment:
      - TZ=Asia/Shanghai
      - PASSWORD=1
      - RSTUDIO_VERSION=2024.04.2+764
      - R_VERSION=4.4.1

Following the above YAML, I have successfully deployed RStudio, and I can access it through the browser without issues. However, why is the version of RStudio that I have deployed RStudio 2021.09.1+372 with R version 4.1.2? How can I deploy the latest versions of RStudio and R?
